# InApp Purchase verifyReceipt (error -42351)

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, itunes-store

I could not find a better place for this post, so please tell me if I have picked the wrong one.

Starting around 2 days ago the we have been having periodic trouble verifiying some iOS InApp Purchase receipts (i.e. posting the receipt for verification to the https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt URL)

They are all rejected by the apple server with the error: -42351. I do not find any reference to this error anywhere on the Apple Site or online.

Upon inspection of the payload received from the application it looks relatively ok, e.g. the payload looks like other "valid" ones, and there is no obviously missing or spoofed signature in the decoded payload data..

Has anyone else had this error, or can anyone point me in the direction of documents as to what this might mean?

Thanks!
Tyler

Answer (score -1):

Found more details regarding this error on the Apple Developer Forums if anyone is interested.

https://devforums.apple.com/message/807442#807442